# C# changing variables from different cs file and serial reading

Tags: c#, variables, windows-10-iot-core

Hi I'm new to programming and new to even more newer at C#.

I wanted to create a second file to make everything look a bit cleaner but it doesn't work out.

It's an UWP background project for a RP3 running Windows 10 IoT core.

I want to make a webserver that can be accessed by an app but I haven't made that code yet, obviously. 
Now I'm trying to figure out the connection between the Arduino and the RP. It works perfectly for the most part.

But I wanted to make it look better so I wanted to put all the sensor stuff in a different file but I can't access or change any variable.
For example, I want to change clState to true/false, I can't do that.

Another problem I have is that when the arduino sends a single string through serial, the RP receives it and it works perfectly but if I send multiple strings (for example multiple Serial.write) it receives it but my code that checks if it's correct only works for on of the strings... I suspect it has something to do with the asynchronous stuff but I don't know how to fix it. But that is less important.

```
                    rcvdText = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Succesvol gelezen van Arduino");
                    Debug.WriteLine(rcvdText);
                    char startMarker = '<';
                    char endMarker = '>';
                    if (rcvdText.Contains(startMarker) == true && rcvdText.Contains(endMarker) == true)
                    {
                        int startIndex = rcvdText.IndexOf(startMarker) + 1;
                        int endIndex = rcvdText.IndexOf(endMarker) - 1;
                        receivedChars = rcvdText.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                        Debug.WriteLine(receivedChars);
                        CheckNewData();
                    }
```

All help is very much appreciated! :)

*Sorry the indentation failed when copying... And I think I didn't follow the naming convention...*

This is the main file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

namespace ArduinoData
{

  public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
  {
    //public bool clState;
    public ArduinoConnect test2 = new ArduinoConnect();
    BackgroundTaskDeferral serviceDeferral;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        serviceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        BackgroundTaskDeferral arduinoDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        //ArduinoConnect test = new ArduinoConnect();
        test2.WatchDevice();
        Test();
        test2.clState = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is ArduinoConnect.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace ArduinoData

{

  public sealed class ArduinoConnect
  {
    DataReader dataReaderObject = null;
    private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
    private CancellationTokenSource ReadCancellationTokenSource;
    private string rcvdText;
    private string receivedChars;

    //variabelen voor status
    private bool clState;
    private bool phPlusState;
    private bool phMinState;
    private bool pompState;
    private bool lampenState;
    private bool warmteState;
    private bool vulState;
    private bool waterState;
    private byte dekState;

    public void WatchDevice()
    {
        UInt16 vid = 0x2341;
        UInt16 pid = 0x0001;

        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);

        var Watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(aqs);

        Watcher.Added += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>(DeviceAdded);

        Watcher.Removed += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>(OnDeviceRemoved);

        Watcher.Start();
    }

    private async void DeviceAdded(DeviceWatcher watcher, DeviceInformation device)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Apparaat gevonden! :)");
        try
        {
            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: " + device.Name + " verbonden!!! :D");

            serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Seriële poort succesvol geconfigureerd! :D");
            ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Fout bij Seriële poort configureren. :(");
        }
        Listen();
    }

    private async void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Listen() function");
            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);

                // keep reading the serial input
                while (true)
                {
                    await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Reading task was cancelled, closing device and cleaning up");
            CloseDevice();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Cleanup once complete
            if (dataReaderObject != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject.DetachStream();
                dataReaderObject = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        // If task cancellation was requested, comply
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream

            loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);

            // Launch the task and wait
            UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                rcvdText = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Succesvol gelezen van Arduino");
                Debug.WriteLine(rcvdText);
                char startMarker = '<';
                char endMarker = '>';
                if (rcvdText.Contains(startMarker) == true && rcvdText.Contains(endMarker) == true)
                {
                    int startIndex = rcvdText.IndexOf(startMarker) + 1;
                    int endIndex = rcvdText.IndexOf(endMarker) - 1;
                    receivedChars = rcvdText.Substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                    Debug.WriteLine(receivedChars);
                    CheckNewData();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void CheckNewData()
    {
        switch (receivedChars)
        {
            case "CL_STATE=0" :
                clState = false;
                break;

            case "CL_STATE=1" :
                clState = true;
                break;

            case "PHPLUS_STATE=0" :
                phPlusState = false;
                break;

            case "PHPLUS_STATE=1" :
                phPlusState = true;
                break;

            case "POMP_STATE=0" :
                pompState = false;
                break;

            case "POMP_STATE=1" :
                pompState = false;
                break;

            case "LAMPEN_STATE=0" :
                lampenState = false;
                break;

            case "LAMPEN_STATE=1" :
                lampenState = true;
                break;

            case "VUL_STATE=0" :
                vulState = false;
                break;

            case "VUL_STATE=1" :
                vulState = true;
                break;

            case "WATER_STATE=0" :
                waterState = false;
                break;

            case "WATER_STATE=1" :
                waterState = true;
                break;

            case "DEK_STATE=0" :
                dekState = 0;
                break;

            case "DEK_STATE=1" :
                dekState = 1;
                break;

            case "DEK_STATE=2" :
                dekState = 2;
                break;

            case "REFRESH=1" :
                Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Refresh uitgevoerd!");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Fout commando!");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnDeviceRemoved(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate device)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Apparaat losgekoppeld.");
        try
        {
            CancelReadTask();
            CloseDevice();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void CancelReadTask()
    {
        if (ReadCancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            if (!ReadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ReadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CloseDevice()
    {
        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
        }
        serialPort = null;

        rcvdText = "";
    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have a new problem with this code I had the same problem sometimes with my old code above...

**Error**
*Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length*

*I can't paste it correctly, it's annoying...*

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        rcvdText = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Debug: Succesvol gelezen van Arduino");
                        Debug.WriteLine(rcvdText);

                        //char startMarker = '<';
                        //char endMarker = '>';


                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var ch in rcvdText)
                        {
                            //if (ch != '\u+003C') continue;
                            if (ch == '\u003C')
                            {
                                StartIndex = i + 1;
                                Debug.WriteLine(StartIndex);
                            }
                            if (ch == '\u003E')
                            {
                                EndIndex = i - 1;
                                Debug.WriteLine(EndIndex);
                                receivedChars = rcvdText.Substring(StartIndex, EndIndex);
                                Debug.WriteLine(receivedChars);
                                StartIndex = 0;
                                EndIndex = 0;
                            }
                            i++;
                            Debug.WriteLine("test");
                        }
                        Debug.WriteLine("finished");
                    }
```

And the Debug output:

```
Debug: Succesvol gelezen van Arduino
<WATER_STATE=1>
<WATER_STATE=0>

1
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
13
WATER_STATE=1
test
test
test
18
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
30
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
test2
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
test2
The program '[2888] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

**EDIT2 I figured it out, I'm an idiot...**

Comment: clState is private, it needs to be public to access it from another class.

Comment: You cant modify a private field outside of the class itself - you either need to make it public (though this is generally considered bad practice) or provide a public property or method for setting it. As for checking multiple messages, your code only appears to check for the first instance of start/end marker - you need to iterate through the entire of the string for each message.

Comment: @Simon I can't make it public error: "Fields can be exposed only by structures"

Comment: @PaulF Can I do this if I 'Instantiate' (sorry I'm dutch, I forgot the word...) the class with something like this: 'private ArduinoConnect test = new ArduinoConnect();'

Comment: So the best thing to do is move all that stuff back into the main background file?
And @PaulF Thank you for your suggestion for the markers, I'll try it :)

Comment: As per PaulF's comment, you can either provide a public property (with a getter and setter) or a method for updating the field.

Comment: Keeping separate classes is the correct way to go - what you should do is provide public properties or methods to access the private fields. See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: Thanks I looked into it and I think I understand it but I still don't know how I can change clState with the property ClState (is this correct?)

'public bool ClState
        {
            get
            {
                return clState;
            }
            set
            {
                clState = value;
            }
        }'

Comment: You can using [auto-implementing properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) like this:`public bool clState { get; set; }`.

Comment: I tried to do it but I failed :) I moved it back to the main file, I think that's easier, thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT @PaulF @Simon Thank you all for your answers I figured it out :)
So in the end I did this: `public bool ClState { get; set; }` I didn't know I could call it like a class.
Someone may write an answer and I'll accept it :)

I have a new problem with the chars I edited my orginal post

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I wanted to make it look better so I wanted to put all the sensor
>   stuff in a different file but I can't access or change any variable.
>   For example, I want to change clState to true/false, I can't do that.

You can using auto-implementing properties like this:

```
public bool clState { get; set; }
```

More information you can reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).